# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'TimerExeption' with no type

Tags: c++, exception

I'm getting this error when trying to throw an exception of type TimerException in my timer.cpp file. here is timer_exception.h

```
  1 #ifndef TIMER_EXCEPTION_H
  2 #define TIMER_EXCEPTION_H
  3                              
  4 #include <iostream>
  5 #include <string>   
  6                                                                        
  7 class TimerException{         
  8         friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const TimerException e){
  9                 std::cout << " *** TIMER EXCEPTION *** " << e.message;
 10                 return os;    
 11         }                                
 12 public:                         
 13         TimerExeption(std::string message) : message(message) {}
 14 private:                        
 15         std::string message;                   
 16 };                                         
 17                       
 18                                 
 19 #endif
```

and here is my timer.cpp file where the TimerException is being instantiated

```
  1 #include <ctime>
  2 #include "timer.h"
  3 #include "timer_exception.h" 
  4 
  5 void Timer::start(){
  6         if(timer != 0) throw TimerException("Timer already started");
  7         this->timer = clock();
  8 }
```

Comment: Why doesn't your exception class inherit from `std::exception`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Note: It should inherit from `std::exception`; but it's perfectly valid not to.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yes, I understand that.  I just want to know what his reason is for not doing it, or if he simply doesn't know that he should.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was actually unaware there was such a thing, I'll look into it on my own time but this was for an assignment for school so i'm just going with the flow. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

Simple typo. You're missing a 'c' in your constructor's name.

```
13         TimerExeption(std::string message) : message(message) {}
//               ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor has a typo.  TimerExeption, the c is missing.